# Force git to merge in commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase

We have been trying to merge 2 branches together for a couple of days now yet we still have a few problems. Git appears to skip some commits that it believes are already in the branch.

If we run `git branch --contains CommitHash` then it shows the commit to be in the develop branch, however if we run git log on the folder the commit contains it doesn't show the commit in the branch.

Is there a way to force git to merge in these commits?

Any help would be appreciate as it

Andy

Comment: What happens if you try `git log --full-history`?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN force those commits over to the other branch using git cherry-pick, but I don't recommend it, since you are probably just looking over the change in the log.

Comment: No I've checked the logs and they are not there, infact the entire folder isnt there.

Comment: That seem strange. Try running "git show [sha1]" of the commit that is missing. See if the commit actually involves files in the folder you are git-logging.